# How to run subversion cleanly, ignoring any configuration area data and saved data

Tags: svn

For some investigation and diagnostic purpose(about svn's NTLM authentication behavior), I want to run svn.exe as client, from time to time. But I'm facing a problem:

- Case 1: Some commands store data in its configuration directory, `%APPDATA%\Subversion`. For example, if you don't run with `--no-auth-cache`, your username & password will be silently stored, which influences the behavior of its next run, and I don't want that influence.
- Case 2: Sometimes I have to diagnose svn NLTM problem for other svn client machines, so I'd like to run svn.exe cleanly, without any disturbance of external configuration.

This is particular important for Windows client machine, because from this [doc page](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.confarea.html), we know that there are FOUR places(two registry location, two file system folders) that can influence svn's running behavior, -- checking each of them becomes very boring task.

So, is there some secret command-line option or environment settings that makes svn.exe run absolutely cleanly?

Currently using Collabnet Subversion 1.8.11 .

Answer (score 0):

> So, is there some secret command-line option or environment settings that makes svn.exe run absolutely cleanly?

Doubtful. That doesn't sound like a use case that many, if any, users would need.

Possible workarounds include running it in a different account (e.g. with `runas`) or in a VM.

Comment: Oh yes, I think I'm not among those average users since several month ago. The idea is: when something goes wrong, there should be a way to "run with factory default".